# Multidonut chart d3 legendds not working

Tags: d3.js

I am a d3 newbie . I was trying to create a multidonut chart.
but I am not getting the legend columns.I have added my code here

http://jsfiddle.net/YsvT8/

i tried to add this code

```
var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("width", radius * 2)
      .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

but my page is not loading.
I not able to figure out what changes I need make to get the legends on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It Will give you required output.

```
 var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("width", radius * 2)
        .attr("height", radius * 2)
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(pairs) //Changed this line from your code
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

        legend.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);

        legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.key; });//Changed this line from your code
```

Comment: It is working but the color of legends is coming the same for all.